# Scheme Why does it seem that my else statement is not working?

Tags: scheme

. I am trying to teach my self some computer science skills independently. The problem I am working on wants me to create a way to choose the two biggest numbers out of three then find the sum of squares for the two numbers.

```
(define (pro x y z) 
  (cond( (and (< x y) (< x z)) (define a y)(define b z))
       ( (and(< y x) (< y z)) (define a x) (define b z))
       ( else ((define a x )(define b y))))
  (+ (* a a) (* b b))
```

When I run the function with z being the smallest or tied for the smallest number I get the following error:

```
Error: #<undef> is not a function [pro, (anon)]
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

I have been using repl.it to run this program, if that matters.

Comment: Why does your `else` branch say `((define` when the other two only have `(define`?

Comment: I thought to get it to do both defines i needed to put them in put an extra set of brackets, but getting rid of that set of brackets made it work thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, using define's that way is totally bizarre for Scheme code.

After that, I see two problems with the code.  The first, the one that's creating the error you're getting, is that you have an extra layer of parens in the else clause.  The following

((define a x) (define b y))

is going to evaluate the first define and try to apply it as a procedure.  The evaluation of (define ...) returns the #undef which is the source of your error messsage.

If you fixed that problem, your next problem is that your sum of squares code is outside the scope of the defines in your cond and you'll find that a and b are not defined out there.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
(define (max-of-3 x y z)
  (cond
    ((and (< x y) (< x z)) (values y z))
    ((and (< y x) (< y z)) (values x z))
    (else                  (values x y))))

(define (pro x y z)
  (let-values (((a b) (max-of-3 x y z)))
    (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
```

or even

```
(define (pro x y z)
  (let-values
      (((a b) (cond
                ((and (< x y) (< x z)) (values y z))
                ((and (< y x) (< y z)) (values x z))
                (else                  (values x y)))))
    (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
```